# Centering Bootstrap Cards in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When in mobile view, cards are not centring as expected.

I have tried using d-flex and justify-content-center as suggested in a previous answer to no avail.

I've noticed that adding mx-auto to each of the card classes sort of works and keeps them nicely centered, however, the gap between the cards is also removed using this method.

Please see my site [here](http://nullnova.co.uk/).

Looks fine in desktop view, but once in mobile view all the cards are pushed to the right, I can see that the cards are going over the margin-right defined in my main tag.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <main>
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="card-deck mx-auto">
      <!--Games Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3 d-flex" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="../img/games.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Games">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Games</strong></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Consoles Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="##">
        <img src="../img/consoles.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Consoles">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Consoles</strong></p>
        </div>
      </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Getting Started Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="###">
        <img src="../img/gettingStarted.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Getting Started">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Getting Started</strong></p>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please dont fixed the width for your card. use `style="width: auto;"` instead of `style="width: 18rem;"` this will solve your problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <main>
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="card-deck mx-auto">
      <!--Games Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3 d-flex" style="width: auto;">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="../img/games.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Games">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><strong>Games</strong></p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Consoles Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: auto;">
        <a href="##">
          <img src="../img/consoles.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Consoles">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><strong>Consoles</strong></p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Getting Started Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: auto;">
        <a href="###">
          <img src="../img/gettingStarted.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Getting Started">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><strong>Getting Started</strong></p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please accept this as an accepted answer please :) @ScottWilks

Answer (score 0):

if you put the **align-items-center** class in card-deck parent div you can get center card.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <main>
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="card-deck mx-auto align-items-center">
      <!--Games Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3 d-flex" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="../img/games.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Games">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Games</strong></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Consoles Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="##">
        <img src="../img/consoles.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Consoles">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Consoles</strong></p>
        </div>
      </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Getting Started Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="###">
        <img src="../img/gettingStarted.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Getting Started">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Getting Started</strong></p>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way is to add `margin:0 auto;` to the card-deck div!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <main>
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="card-deck" style="margin:0 auto">
      <!--Games Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3 d-flex" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="../img/games.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Games">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Games</strong></p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Consoles Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="##">
        <img src="../img/consoles.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Consoles">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Consoles</strong></p>
        </div>
      </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Getting Started Card-->
      <div class="card text-center text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="###">
        <img src="../img/gettingStarted.png" href="#" class="card-img-top" alt="Getting Started">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><strong>Getting Started</strong></p>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!--JavaScript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```